# Is there a way to have scheduled push notifications on parse server?

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, parse-server

I read on the parse-server-example wiki guide that the parse server will not be supporting scheduled push notifications. Is there any possible way around this while still using my own parse server? Maybe with cloud code??? (I have deployed the server with heroku and MongoDB.)

Answer (score 1):

Parse Server itself does not have yet any feature for scheduling push notifications. But you can create a cloud code function to do the push notifications and schedule a call to it using crontab.